# How to solve redirection loop error in IIS8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

Hi I'm taking redirection loop error in live page because of so many 301 redirection requests and can't view What I want for Google search robot.And interesting thing is when I test it local test page, it's OK.
How to end this loop by using my web.config class?

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>        
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true" >
      <match url="(.*robots.txt)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"  />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it's a URL rewrite module bug in IIS 8.5. Try installing [x86 patch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47336) or [x64 patch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) depending on deployment machine's platform, also you can use Firebug to find out redirects to certain page continuously.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto dude these have same machine platform,nothing  any difference.